# How to repackage an outdated .app installer for monterey

Tags: install, monterey

I want to install an audio plugin from a developer that isn't very active.
The installer comes in the .app format and i was wondering if it is possible to repackage it for Monterey; I've tried "Repackage" form Twocanoes but that doesn't seem to work... possible extraction scripts and outdated directories.

So, i was wondering if anyone had a solution or if could use Packages from Stephanie Sudre (http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html)

NB: not quite the developer so i'd need some guidance, thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the original run? What OS was it built for & how long ago? What's the plugin? What type, AU, VST etc?

Comment: Also have you *contacted* the developer of the audio plugin and/or the Packages dev?